# Is 'Archive' a reserved word in Rails or SQLite3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

After migrating a model named 'Archive', all tests fail with an ActiveRecord / error message along the lines of:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: archives.created_at: INSERT INTO "archives" ("some_thing") VALUES ('MyString')
```

This was isolated in a new Rails app on a new VM running a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.2 with Ruby 2.6.1 and Rails 5.2.3, following The Odin Project's installation instructions.  The problem only arises during tests for models named 'Archive', and removing the model's attributes just changes the error to:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: incomplete input: INSERT INTO "archives"
```

My work flow is as follows:

```
rails new sample_app

cd sample_app
```

(change sqlite3 in Gemfile to use version '~> 1.3.6' to fix bug at time of this writing)

```
bundle install

rails g model Archive
```

Generates this migration:

```rb
class CreateArchives < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :archives do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
rails db:migrate
```

Creates this schema:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_04_03_003144) do

  create_table "archives", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

```
rails db:test
```

Runs this test: (uncommented)

```rb
require 'test_helper'

class ArchiveTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

After running the test, which would normally be a given pass, Rails returns the first ActiveRecord error message listed above.
I feel like I am missing something here that prevents me from using the word 'Archive' for a model.

Comment: also share you schema.rb, specially for "Archive" and you test file

Comment: Just added the schema, migration, and model test to the question.

Comment: It looks like 'archive' might be a reserved word in Rails, according to [this list](https://gist.github.com/ryo0508/9225700).

Answer (score 0):

`Archive` is not a reserved word. The link you have provided is not updated in last 5 years.

The reason behind this is:

You are creating a record of Archive without providing `created_at` and `updated_at` which are mandatory fields as per your `schema`.

```
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
```

***Solution:***

Either change your migrations to allow `null` to be inserted in `created_at` and `updated_at` OR go to you `test/fixtures/archive.yml` and provide `created_at` and `updated_at` there.

like:

```
one:
  ....some fields....
  created_at: 2018-08-30 14:41:23
  updated_at: 2018-08-30 14:41:23
```

**UPDATE**

Now second issue is because you don't have any field other than `timestamp`. Drop this table and create new model for Archive with at least 1 field. Currently Rails is generating query `INSERT INTO "Archives";` and SQL expects data after this query, that's why it returns error to you.

Comment: This actually solves the test problem, but there is still the mystery of this only happening on models with the name 'Archive' here.  A Fixture of a model by another name, ie.- 'Archived', will auto-generate those two columns by default.

Comment: Antoher thing: removing the timestamps from the migration, or setting them to [allow null](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table/timestamps) results in a the second error listed above.